# Simple Linux script to find and combine artifacts into txt file

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I almost weekly need to check our build artifacts to make sure everythying is accounted for.  This script is bellow.  I'm unable to run this command.

```
#!/bin/bash 

cd /mydir/nextlevel/here
find . -name *.rpm > ~/rpm.txt
find . -name *.zip > ~/zip.txt

cd ~/
cat rpm.txt zip.txt > artifacts.txt

rm rpm.txt zip.txt

mv artifacts.txt /newdir/myname
```

Comment: What issue do you have?  Sourcing isn't what you are looking for.  I have a hunch maybe either the file is not executable or you are not prefixing with `./` when you run.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) explain what you want the script to do; ii) explain what it is actually doing; iii) show us how you launch it and iv) what the error message you get (if any) is.

Comment: Jesse_b I think you are correct.  I had to run dos2unix on the .sh file and it worked.  

terdon Thank you for the suggestions, I will make sure I take into account next post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue are the two lines

```
find . -name *.rpm > ~/rpm.txt
find . -name *.zip > ~/zip.txt
```

... and the way that `*.rpm` and `*.zip` are *not* quoted on those lines.

This means that e.g. `*.rpm` will expand to `file1.rpm file2.rpm` etc. (all names matching the pattern) *before* `find` is even invoked. This will likely cause `find` to complain about "unknown option" (or similar).

Instead, you'd like to pass the file name patterns unexpanded:

```
find . -name '*.rpm' > ~/rpm.txt
find . -name '*.zip' > ~/zip.txt
```

This would make your script work.

---

Suggestion:

```
#!/bin/sh

find /mydir/nextlevel/here -type f \( -name '*.rpm' -o -name '*.zip' \) -print >/newdir/myname
```

This combines every single operation that your script is doing into one single command that finds the files that have the particular file name suffixes and collects their names in the file `/newdir/myname`.

The only difference is that the *full* path (including `/mydir/nextlevel/here`) would be included in the listing for every file, and that the files may be listed in a different order.

The following script would fix the path in the output file:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /mydir/nextlevel/here &&
find . -type f \( -name '*.rpm' -o -name '*.zip' \) -print >/newdir/myname
```

The `find` is additionally now carried out *only* if the `cd` is successful.

Answer (score 1):

This single command would do all the job you are doing:

```
find /mydir/nextlevel/here \( -name "*.rpm" -o -name "*.zip" \) \
    > /newdir/myname/artifacts.txt
```